# LESS extend is not working for the imported css

Tags: css, less, mixins

I'm trying to combine class names in to one using LESS extend mixin and this simple example is not giving expected results:

```
@import (less) "//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css";

.todoFlag:extend(.fa .fa-flag all) {
    color: red;
}
```

The `.fa-flag` class above in imported css has only one selector like this:

```
.fa-flag:before {
  content: "\f024";
}
```

The result of compilation is this:

```
.todoFlag {
  color: red;
}
```

I was expecting `.todoFlag` will have `:before` due to extend but above is the only lines generated for todoFlag in compiled css.

Am I using the extend correctly? Does extend works on classes imported like above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out (thanks to [Mária Jurčovičová](https://github.com/SomMeri/less4j/wiki/Less-Language-Extends)'s excellent writeup on this "hidden" feature of LESS).

The `.todoFlag:extend(.fa .fa-flag all)` actually extends fa-flag as descendant on fa. In reality fa-flag is not a descendant of fa so that statement has no effect. What I'd actually like to achieve was replace the multiple classes in to one class. So if you have,

```
<i class="fa fa-flag redColor"></i>
```

I want to replace that with,

```
<i class="todoFlag"></i>
```

To do this, todoFlag needs to first inherit everything from fa, including all pseudo selectors such as `:after` and then it needs to inherit from fa-flag. To achieve this, we need to use a feature of LESS extend that allows this kind of multiple inheritance. The syntax for this is,

```
.todoFlag:extend(.fa all):extend(.fa-flag all) {
    .redColor;
}
```

So basically, you call extend twice with each class. And it works!

Comment: The shorter syntax for `.todoIcon:extend(.fa all):extend(.fa-flag all) ` is `.todoIcon:extend(.fa all, .fa-flag all)`. You also can find up-to-date LESS `extend` documentation [here](https://github.com/less/less-docs/blob/master/content/features/extend.md)

Comment: Note that unfortunately this will only work on the "CSS" version of FontAwesome and NOT the "Less" version as the referenced fa classes do not exist until compiled, therefore the extend function simply silently fails and does not extend the definitions to the target class. I've just spent 3 hours trying to figure out why it wouldn't work.

Comment: what make `&:extend();` not to work, and only `:extend(){` work? also i see some user do `:extend(c1, c2){` why it doesnt work for me and i have to define them one by one `:extend(c1):extend(c2){`

Answer (score 2):

`.todoFlag:extend(.fa .fa-flag all)` extends `.fa .fa-flag` blocks only (but "font-awesome.css" has no such ruleset). To extend just `.fa-flag` you need:

```
.todoFlag:extend(.fa-flag all)
```

If you need to extend both `.fa` and `.fa-flag` use:

```
.todoFlag:extend(.fa all, .fa-flag all)
```